# R: Creating data frame with random values for different type types

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

TASK 1:I'm looking to create a dataframe in R where I want to have the columns: items, quantity, price. All the values needs to be random though.

After this, I need to create 10 versions of this list with randomly assigned quantities, each quantity needs to be 0 or more.

TASK2: Now that we have an inventory list: 1) Take 1 inventory list. 2) Randomly sample 25 items from the list 3) Take the store quantity, divide by 10 and round to an integer 4) These items and quantities become the cargo 5) The sumproduct of the cargo price * quantity becomes the cargo value 6) make up a cargo weight.

Any help for TASK2 would be appreciated.

Comment: What is a sumproduct? Make up a cargo weight, how? Does store quantity = quantity from one of the 10 inventroy lists? Do the "10 versions of this list" need to be sampled from the dataframe in TASK 1 or what? Task2.1) are we sampling from the 10 lists or the df from task 1? Do you want or execute task 2 for all 10 lists or just the df from task 1?

Comment: Sumproduct is the basic A*B + C*D. Cargo weight meaning the name of the variable needs to be that. Store quantity is basically the sum of all the quantities in 1 list. 

Yes, the 10 versions of the list needs to have the same items, price as the one made in List1 but the quantity needs to change in every list.

Task2: Yes, we can take any 1 of the list, so, let's take df from task1. So, this needs to be done for all the 10 lists.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully get if that's what you're looking for but, how about:

```
df <- data.frame(items=sample(LETTERS,10,replace=FALSE),quantity=sample(1:100,10,replace=FALSE),price=sample(100:1000,10,replace=FALSE))

write.table(df,file ='table.txt',quote=FALSE,row.names = F)
```

Comment: Hi, 

This does create a data frame which I want but I'm looking for a realistic data set. For eg: Imagine it to be a transaction data for a day for Target. So, obviously, the quantity and price has to be realistic. 

The next problem is: Now that we have an inventory list: 1) Take 1 inventory list. 2) Randomly sample 25 items from the list 3) Take the store quantity, divide by 10 and round to an integer 4) These items and quantities become the cargo 5) The sumproduct of the cargo price * quantity becomes the cargo value 6) make up a cargo weight.

Thanks!

Comment: According to what you posted, my solution seems to be sufficient. Now, while it's up to you if you accept/like it, I suggest that you read up a bit regarding the specific things you want to do. There are plenty excellent resources in the interwebs and on StackOverflow, that's the best way to learn. If you're still stuck, you should ask a more specific question. In the end, SO is about helping people and learning, not doing someone else's work.

Comment: Thanks for that Val. This is just a part of stuff where I'm stuck and I can handle the rest of the things if this one is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively general solution:

```
df <- data.frame(Item=sample(c("bike","computer", "milk","eggs","pants","flux capacitor","sonic screwdriver"), 25, replace = T),
                 quantity=rpois(25, 2),
                 price=rnorm(25, 100, 25))

write.csv(df, file = "data.txt", row.names = F, col.names = T)
```

`sample` works well for picking items out of a bag with or without replacement, you can also set the probability of picking each item.

`rpois` draws from a poisson distribution, which to me resemebles quantities pretty well

`rnorm` draws from a the normal distribution could also use `runif`

Comment: Thanks. The next problem is:

Now that we have an inventory list:

 1) Take 1 inventory list.
 2) Randomly sample 25 items from the list
 3) Take the store quantity, divide by 10 and round to an integer
 4) These items and quantities become the cargo
 5) The sumproduct of the cargo price * quantity becomes the cargo value
 6) make up a cargo weight

Comment: Please ask a new question or edit your current question to be complete. Please have a look at how to make a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example